# Spring Boot Actuator in same contextPath from camel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to utilize Spring Boot Actuator but utilizing the same context-path from camel, is that possible?

here I set the context_path in camel

application.yml

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath: ${CONTEXT_PATH}
```

I've tried many ways

```
server.servlet.context-path: ${CONTEXT_PATH}
```

but this way doesn't found camel route.

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details: 'always'
management.endpoints.web.base-path: ${CONTEXT_PATH}/actuator/**
```

this way returns 404.

My camel path is

```
localhost:8080/api-context
```

And I need to utilize Actuator and Health in

```
localhost:8080/api-context/actuator
localhost:8080/api-context/actuator/health
```

Comment: Hi&Welcome to [SO]! What you show is rather `.properties` syntax not `.yaml`. But generally I would solve your problem by: 1. fix/ensure working camel path (on `/api-context`) 2. Set  `management.endpoints.web.base-path: /api-context/actuator/**` (assuming `server.servlet.context-path=/`)

Comment: @xerx593, thank you so much! I've tried this, but when I run actuator, returns 404.

localhost:8080/api/actuator = 404

`camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath: /api/*` 
`server.servlet.context-path: /`
`management.endpoints.web.base-path: /api/actuator/**`

Comment: please also share your camel/springboot version

Comment: camel 3.4.0, spring 2.3.1